# Updating an object with time intervals

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, refresh

This could be more of asking for suggestions, but hear me out.

I have an object that has to be refreshed every preset period of time (the time is specified by the user). The amount of objects will most likely reach around 1000 if not more.

I came up with three methods and I want to find the performance issues of using certain ones.

I thought of either using a timer for each object, adding and event to it and when the timer reaches a certain value, fire that event, set the object's state to Refresh, and when the next packet of data comes in, refresh that certain object

==or==

Have a timer thread that just runs the timer, and every the amount of ticks hit the multiplier of that (10 mins, 5 mins etc.), it would call upon the objects with that multiple and set the Refresh flags, and when the packets come in, refresh those.

I'm not sure if adding a timer to every object is a good idea because of the load.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid adding a timer to every object. Perhaps you can have a separate thread which is responsible for initiating updates on your objects. You can use [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx) to run concurrent updates on all of your if you think this won't cause concurrency issues. For example, something like:

```
Thread updateThread = new Thread(updateLoop);
IEnumerable<Updateable> _updateableObjects;
public static void Main()
{
    updateThread.Start();
} 

private static function UpdateLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(_updateableObjects, obj => obj.Update());
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```